# Should we lax up on the questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, moderation

I know that the makers (and mods) of the site want it to be geared toward "top level" players, but should we go easy on the "rookie" questions until the site starts to generate a little more traffic?

The patrolling for duplicate questions has been exemplary, and **simple** rules questions are being controlled appropriately. For more difficult rules questions, and some "rookie" strategy talk, I think they should be encouraged through the infancy of the .SE

IMHO of course.

Comment: I'm interested to know what you think is happening to these "rookie" questions so far? Also, if you have *any* type of strategy question, just ask it! See how it goes.

Comment: Do you have a link to one of the "rookie" questions that got closed (or is at risk of being closed?)?

Comment: I haven't seen any examples of rookie questions getting closed (I haven't been around that much though) but I would strongly suggest that they get treated with the same level of respect as a more advanced level question.